# Running an old project, dependency errors from ESLint. How do I solve this?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, eslint

So i'm trying to running an  old project from 2019, there are problems from Eslint,
I tried adding new versions to see if it would work, but it's still causing conflicts, and npm run dev doesn't run.
I've already tried deleting node_modules and .nuxt multiple times and running npm install multiple times. I've also tried npm install --legacy-peer-deps. The node_modules folder gets installed, but ESLint erros prevents the project from running.

My package.json file looks like this:
[image]

The errors I'm seeing are:
[image]

I have already tried removing Eslint from the project, but it seems that the project doesn't run properly without Eslint. I'm not sure why, but I'm getting errors related to page requests when Eslint is not present.

Comment: The error means what it says, eslint-related package versions a mismatched. This is because >= version constraints are used. Stick to the ones that are in your lock file which you're supposed to have. Replace them with respective ^ at least to avoid this in future. Btw `node: 13` restriction is another problem

Comment: I can put ^ in everything or only in eslint-related package? okk i'll put in node too, thanks!

Comment: engine may be not respected by package manager, it's up to you to use proper node versions consistently. 13 isn't one, even ones are stable, odd are experimental. You can put any semver anywhere. ~ and ^ are safer than >=